# Windows Server 2008 group policy

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have created four user groups in Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise which are:

- Staff1
- Staff2
- Staff3
- Public

How can I add different group polices to any of these user groups?

Comment: Just to clear something up - Group Policy is poorly named. GPOs are generally assigned to organizational units (OUs), not groups. Later versions of AD allow for WMI filtering and security filtering can be used as joeqwerty says but I don't think it is widely used practice.

Answer (score 5):

Create the relevant GPO's. Link the GPO's to the OU where these user accounts exist (or to the domain if the users are in the default Users container). Use Security Filtering on the GPO to remove Authenticated Users and add the appropriate group. Done.